# Add HTML Class after 3 elements in PHP

Tags: php, html, foreach, str-replace

My HTML should seen like this;

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Car</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Google</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Building</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Bathroom</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Facebook</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Twitter</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

In database, all data is in same field with there is a comma between them(e.g. Car,Google,Building,Bathroom, Facebook, Twitter).

So, I'm using this code to seperate them;

```
<?php echo str_replace(',', '</li><li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>', $data); ?>
```

I need to get the same result with HTML, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by with html?

Comment: My code should be the same structure with HTML sample.

Comment: y u save comma delimited?

Comment: I'm saving data in database like this: "Car,Google,Building,Bathroom, Facebook, Twitter". There is no space between comma.

Comment: php is the only way to manipulate your data... you can't do this with "pure html"... but, btw, why are you using closing tag first, then leave an opened one (within your str_replace code)? you should open/close your "li" tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arrData = explode(",", $data); // comma separated list of words
$i = 0; // temp counter

echo '<div class="row">';
foreach ($arrData as $word)
{
    if ($i==0) { echo '<div class="col-xs-6"><ul class="list-unstyled">'; } // open first html containers

    echo  '<li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>'.$word.'</li>'; // create li

    $i++; // increase counter

    if ($i==2) // this is the 3rd element in loop
    {
        echo '</ul></div>'; // close html containers
        $i=0; // reset counter, so proccess repeats
    }
}
echo '</div>';
```

This code will do what you need, as long as you always have 6 words in your array (or 9, 12, 15, etc).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 $v1=explode(",",$data);
 $data0=$v1[0];
 $data1=$v1[1];
 $data2=$v1[2];
 $data3=$v1[3];
 $data4=$v1[4];
 $data5=$v1[5]; 
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> <?php echo $data0; ?></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>  <?php echo $data1; ?></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>  <?php echo $data2; ?></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>  <?php echo $data3; ?></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>  <?php echo $data4; ?></li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>  <?php echo $data5; ?></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explode and loop through it... look at this and it should help you understand

```
$pieces = explode(",", $data);
foreach($pieces as $value){
     echo  '<li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>'.$value.'</li>';
}
```